# How to return document ID of newly uploaded document in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have already activated the Document ID service and was able to Upload a file to a Sharepoint library using the example found here:

http://www.hoffsays.com/2012/05/02/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-2010-using-c-and-the-sharepoint-web-service/

But I am not sure how to pro-grammatically return the document ID of the newly uploaded document in C#. Anyone who could assist me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **SiteData.GetURLSegments** method.

From [Sharepoint StackExchange, here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/18123/6151).